# Is there a formalization of syllogistic logic?

Tags: logic, reference-request

Is there a book or paper that formalizes Aristotle's syllogistic logic? As in, define the well-formed formulas, define the semantics, define deduction rules, and prove that the deduction rules are both sound and complete?

Comment: Aristotle's syllogistic logic is subsumed by modern predicate logic, e.g. some A's are B's translates to $\exists x: [A(x) \land B(x)]$.

Comment: @DanChristensen But a stronger logic isn't necessarily better: more expressive systems are also generally more computationally intractable. There's good reason to be interested in fragments of (say) first-order logic which are weak enough to have nice computational properties but strong enough to be applicable in specific situations of interest. Also, note that Moss treats a rather broad syllogistic system, including "More $A$s are $B$s" which is generally *not* first-order.

Comment: More than one; at least: J.Lukasiewicz, [Aristotle's syllogistic from the standpoint of modern formal logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=KVMNAQAAMAAJ), G.Patzig, [Aristotle’s Theory of the Syllogism](https://books.google.it/books?id=8g3wCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), J.Lear, [Aristotle and Logical Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=lXI7AAAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: See also J.Corcoran, [Aristotle’s Demonstrative Logic (2009)](http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~corcoran/ADL_HPL_30_2009_1-20_REPRINT.pdf) as well as John Corcoran, [Aristotle's natural deduction system (1974)](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-010-2130-2_6)

Comment: And many more about A's modal syllogism.

Comment: Also useful: Terence Parsons, [Articulating Medieval Logic (Oxford UP, 2014)](https://books.google.it/books?id=hewkAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been studied by Larry Moss - see e.g. [here](https://iulg.sitehost.iu.edu/moss/uwe.pdf). In particular, Moss presented a sound and complete proof system for the whole syllogistic and several of its fragments.

It's worth noting that Moss is by no means the first person to whip up a complete proof system for syllogistic logic. I believe the first was Lukasiewicz, who Moss mentions (and I think Moss's bibliography will in general be helpful). My understanding is that the novel feature of Moss's work is primarily its study of the fragments of syllogistic logic, and so it's worth mentioning for that reason. (I also think it's very well-written, whereas I find a number of papers in the area fairly difficult to read.)

Answer (score 1):

To add another couple of references to those given by @NoahSchweber, there are two must-read classic papers by Timothy Smiley (who by the way shows that Lukasiewicz radically misunderstands what is going on in Aristotle's system). Both papers are eminently clear and straightforward [links are to Jstor, if you have access]:

1. Timothy Smiley, [*Syllogism and Quantification*, JSL 1962](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2963679)
2. Timothy Smiley, [*What is a Syllogism*, JPL 1963](https://www.jstor.org/stable/30226974)